# If $x \in \{1,2,3, \cdots, 9\}$ and $f_n(x) =xxxx\cdots x($ n digits) then find the value of $f_n^2(3)+f_n(2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If $x \in \{1,2,3, \cdots, 9\}$ and $f_n(x) =xxxx\cdots x($ n digits) then find the value of $f_n^2(3)+f_n(2)$

If x =1, then $f_n(1) = ?$ Please suggest how to expand such series. Thanks

Comment: Is $f_n^2(3) = f_n(f_n(3))$ or $(f_n(3))^2$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
f_n(x)={\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^{k}\cdot x}=x\cdot {\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^{k}}=x\cdot\frac{10^n-1}{9}
$$
Due to the fact that it is a geometric progression. This should help you to proceed with $f_n^2(3)+f_n(2)$.

Comment: Cud u please elaborate on that , little theory part how did u get this series? It will be of great help to me thanks

Comment: Well, in base ten, the meaning of every integers representation is that it is equal to the sum of a unique set of multiples of powers of ten. So, mathematically written $n=10^0\cdot a_0+10^1\cdot a_1+\dots$ with $1\le a_i\le9$ (for exampel: $271=10^0\cdot 1+10^1\cdot 7+10^2\cdot 2$). So in your case: $f_n(x)=10^0\cdot x+10^1\cdot x+\dots+10^{n-1}\cdot x=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^k\cdot x$.